# Колонки выпадающие из общей сетки bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, psd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас учусь верстать с помощью bootstrap на тренировочном макете. На картинке я пометил колонки(1, 2) которые не попадают в общую сетку. Как в таких случаях их верстать или прописывать? Поставить **.col** рядом с **.container**?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли поместить колонки в строку вот так:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-2"></div>
       <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так будет работать корректно.